# boost statechart parallel execution of orthogonal states

Tags: c++, boost, parallel-processing, boost-statechart

I've a state machine that has a couple of orthogonal states. These states react to the same event. When the event is sent via `process_event`, a simple benchmark tells me that it is processed sequentially, even though the states are orthogonal to each other.

Is there a way to make these orthogonal states handle the event in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, no, you cannot. Closest you can come is to use [Asynchronous state machines](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/statechart/doc/tutorial.html#AsynchronousStateMachines)